# Determining if variables (integers) are greater or less than 0

Tags: beginner, ruby

Hobbyist here. I think my case/when logic needs to be cleaned up a bit. I'd also appreciate critique on the other parts...but I'm more interested in cleaning up the case/when statements...

```
puts "please assign an integer to x:"
x = gets.chomp.to_i

if (x > 0)
  value_of_x = true
else
  value_of_x = false
end

puts "now please assign an integer to y:"
y = gets.chomp.to_i

if (y > 0)
  value_of_y = true
else
  value_of_y = false
end

case
when (value_of_x == true) && (value_of_y == true)
  puts "two variables are > 0"
when ((value_of_x == true) && (value_of_y == false)) || ((value_of_x == false) && (value_of_y == true))
  puts "at least one variable is > 0"
else
  puts "no variables are > 0"
end
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: If you want to add more variables, @Jonah's approach scales better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will simplify your boolean logic, remove repetition in your input processing, and better express what you're really doing:

```
puts "please assign an integer to x:"
x = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "now please assign an integer to y:"
y = gets.chomp.to_i

num_positive = (x > 0 ? 1 : 0) + (y > 0 ? 1 : 0)

case num_positive
when 2
  puts "two variables are > 0"
when 1
  puts "at least one variable is > 0"
else
  puts "no variables are > 0"
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll Google the num_positive syntax, since this is beyond me at the moment.

Comment: It's called a ternary expression, you can think of it like an if else: `x > 0 ? 1 : 0` means "if x > 0 return 1 otherwise return 0`

Comment: I prefer the block form of count: `num_positive = [x,y].count{|n| n>0}`

Comment: @MarkThomas I agree.  That is nice.  I'd forgotten about `count`

Comment: So the ternary expression evaluates the numerical value of the variable, and assigns a 1 or 0, and the reason this works is because the  ternary expressions can accept arithmetic methods; am I understanding this correctly? It's such clean code.... I'll google my other interest in this new syntactical possibility...

Comment: @DrinkyTheCrow actually, it's much more general than that: `<something that evaluates to true/false> ? <value to return if true> : <value to return if false>`

Comment: You should use `case num_positive` along with `when 2` / `when 1`.

Comment: @Stefan Good point.  Updated.

Answer (score 2):

`#to_i` is not that picky about trailing whitespace.  You don't really need to `#chomp` the input.

Your variables `value_of_x` and `value_of_y` are very misleadingly named.  You can also simplify their assignment, since `(x > 0)` is a boolean expression that will evaluate to either `true` or `false`.

I would rearrange the statements so that all of the input-accepting code appears first.  It's a good habit to separate I/O from computation.

The `((value_of_x == true) && (value_of_y == false)) || ((value_of_x == false) && (value_of_y == true))` case can be simplified, since the both-positive case has already been eliminated by that point.

The `puts` can be factored out, to emphasize that you will print a string no matter which case is true.

```
puts "please assign an integer to x:"
x = gets.to_i
puts "now please assign an integer to y:"
y = gets.to_i

x_is_positive = (x > 0)
y_is_positive = (y > 0)

puts case
when x_is_positive && y_is_positive
  "two variables are > 0"
when x_is_positive || y_is_positive
  "at least one variable is > 0"
else
  "no variables are > 0"
end
```

Alternatively, just get rid of the `…_is_positive` variables altogether, for less clutter.

```
puts "please assign an integer to x:"
x = gets.to_i
puts "now please assign an integer to y:"
y = gets.to_i

puts case
when (x > 0) && (y > 0)
  "two variables are > 0"
when (x > 0) || (y > 0)
  "at least one variable is > 0"
else
  "no variables are > 0"
end
```

Comment: You could also write `x.positive?` instead of `x > 0`.